# about programming with wav files in order to apply dpcm on them

Tags: java, file, audio, wav, prediction

I wonder how I can make a prediction algorithm related to dpcm in order to apply all this compression/modulation to a wav file. I need to make a wav file smaller ()

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of these prediction algorithms already. They are known as "audio compression formats". Pick one and use it.

Comment: Rather than wanting to invent their own algorithm, I'm guessing the poster is essentially asking "how do I tell JavaSound to use the standard ADPCM algorithm when saving a WAV file?". (Unfortunately, I think the answer is "ADPCM is not supported in JavaSound".)